# Adjust Summary and Bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, natbib, titlesec, section-titles, abnt

I ask you, dear colleagues,

I'm having trouble with LaTeX,

I have the following preamble:

```
    \documentclass[
    % -- op\c{c}\~{o}es da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openany,            % cap\'{\i}tulos come\c{c}am em p\'{a}g \'{\i}mpar (insere p\'{a}gina vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impress\~{a}o em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel.
    % -- op\c{c}\~{o}es da classe abntex2 --
    %chapter=TITLE,     % t\'{\i}tulos de cap\'{\i}tulos convertidos em letras mai\'{u}sculas
    %section=TITLE,     % t\'{\i}tulos de se\c{c}\~{o}es convertidos em letras mai\'{u}sculas
    %subsection=TITLE,  % t\'{\i}tulos de subse\c{c}\~{o}es convertidos em letras mai\'{u}sculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% t\'{\i}tulos de subsubse\c{c}\~{o}es convertidos em letras mai\'{u}sculas
    % -- op\c{c}\~{o}es do pacote babel --
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifeniza\c{c}\~{a}o
    %french,            % idioma adicional para hifeniza\c{c}\~{a}o
    %spanish,           % idioma adicional para hifeniza\c{c}\~{a}o
    brazil,             % o \'{u}ltimo idioma \'{e} o principal do documento
    sumario=tradicional,
    ]{abntex2}


% --------------- Enconding | Fonts --------------- %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage{lmodern}           % Usa a fonte Latin Modern      
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{mathpazo}   


%% ----- Other Document Configurations ----- %%
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{cmap}               % Mapear caracteres especiais no PDF
\usepackage{lastpage}           % Usado pela Ficha catalogr\'{a}fica
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro par\'{a}grafo de cada se\c{c}\~{a}o.


%% -------------- Gráfico -------------- %%

%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   % Inclus\~{a}o de gr\'{a}ficos
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Inclus\~{a}o de gr\'{a}ficos
\usepackage{epstopdf}           % Pacote que converte as figuras em eps para pdf

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%% -------------- Colors -------------- %%
\usepackage{color}



% ----------- Layout Rules ----------- %
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


% ----------- Tables ----------- %
\usepackage{ltxtable}               % Fornece a funcionalidade de longtable e tabularx 
\usepackage{booktabs}               % Melhora a Qualidade das Tabelas
\usepackage{tabularx}               % Tabelas
\usepackage{longtable}              % Tabelas Longas
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}   


\usepackage{multirow}



%% ------ Símbolos Matemáticos ------ %%
\usepackage{latexsym}                   % Adicionar Simbolos
\usepackage{pifont}                     % simbolos diferentes | circulos c/ numrs no seu interior, letras gregas, Zapf Dingbats // Exemplo: http://www.uel.br/projetos/matessencial/superior/pdfs/latexmat.pdf (pág 38)

\usepackage{amsmath}                    % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % pacotes matematicos | simbolos
\usepackage{amsthm}                 % pacotes matematicos | teoremas e similares
\usepackage{exscale}                        % pacotes matematicos 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}




%% -------------- Other Packages -------------- %%

% ---
% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no \^{a}mbito do Modelo Can\^{o}nico do zabnteX2
% ---


\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}


\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}


%%% -------------------- Boxes  -------------------- %%%
\usepackage[theorems, most]{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\small}



% ----- CUSTOMIZACAO DO TÍTULO DOS CAPÍTULOS ----- %
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

% ---------------------------------------------------



%%% -------------------- Apendice -------------------- %%%
\usepackage{appendix}
% ****** Rename appendixes in Table of contents ********
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apêndice}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\textsf{Apêndice}}



\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress, numbers]{natbib}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

% informa\c{c}\~{o}es do PDF
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
        %pagebackref=true,
        pdftitle={\@title},
        pdfauthor={\@author},
        pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
        pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
        pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acad\^{e}mico},
        hidelinks,                  % desabilita as bordas dos links
        colorlinks=false,           % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,            % color of internal links  | BLUE
        citecolor=black,                % color of links to bibliography  | BLUE
        filecolor=black,        % color of file links   | MAGENTA
        urlcolor=blue,
%       linkbordercolor={1 1 1},    % set to white
        bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother


%%% >>>>> The rest is customized to the institution (Brazil/Unicamp/ABNT)
```

In the summary the item referring to the bibliography is very distant from the items in the chapters, I would like an equal distance between all items.

[image]

I want a smaller space between the title and the beginning of the page.

```
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

[image]

How will bibliography references be individually in each chapter?

I would like the reference of each chapter to come to the end of the chapter and not to the end of the thesis!

```
\usepackage[semicolon,round,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}  %
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

I tried with the code above and it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your response which I hope will be favorable.

Comment: Instead of `chapterbib` and `natbib`, you should `biblatex-abnt` (check out the manual and the `biblatex` examples. It's always a bad idea to try to beautify what is already ugly (aka `ABNT`), but if you deem it worth your time, you can check out the `memoir` manual and its long, winding intricacies, and/or use another class/package.

Comment: Beautify what's ugly? I agree!

Unfortunately we have to follow the rules.

I'll look at your suggestion. Thanks @BlackBird

Comment: Is your rule really to have chapters with those lines? Weird.